# How to create matrix of tuple coordinates using numpy and then apply a function to each element?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not sure if this is possible to do in `numpy` but what I would like is to create a tuple of coordinates.

For example, for 3x3 matrix I want the matrix to be:

```
[[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2)],
 [(1,0), (1,1), (1,2)],
 [(2,0), (2,1), (2,2)]]
```

Because ultimately I want to pass the coordinates into a function and create a matrix of the func result

So if the function was called `myfunc` had type `(i,j) -> k` I would want the result matrix to look like this

```
[[myfunc(0,0), myfunc(0,1), myfunc(0,2)],
 [myfunc(1,0), myfunc(1,1), myfunc(1,2)],
 [myfunc(2,0), myfunc(2,1), myfunc(2,2)]]
```

And I've looked at solutions like `np.meshgrid`:

```
i_indices, j_indices = np.meshgrid(np.arange(3),np.arange(3),indexing='ij')
```

But then I'm still stuck b/c I don't know how to iterate through those coordinate matrices `i_index` and `j_index` without a for loop to create the resultant matrix I want.

Basically is this possible to do in numpy? If so, how? Or will have have to use a for loop?

Comment: It would be best if `myfunc` could accept the two arrays created by `meshgrid`.  Otherwise you are stuck with some sort of Python level iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Aand I realized I just needed to use `np.vectorize`

```
i_indices, j_index = np.meshgrid(np.arange(3),np.arange(3),indexing='ij')   
myfunc = // some lambda function
v_myfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)    
result_matrix = v_myfunc(i_index, j_indices)
```

Comment: Though `vectorize` is no faster than explicit looping.